# Preferred matrix decomposition

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, cholesky-decomposition, schur-decomposition

Consider a complex square matrix $A\in\mathcal{C}^{n\times n}$. Now let us discuss two kinds of the factorization of $A$, say, **eigendecomposition** and **Schur decomposition** because both of them are often used to factorize square matrices.

My concerns are as follows:

1. Which one of two above-mentioned decomposition techniques is preferable to the other?
2. Which case we should use **eigendecomposition** instead of **Schur decomposition**? Also, could you please give me a detailed explanation?
3. Given that $A$ has extra properties: Hermitian positive definite matrix. In this case, will **Cholesky** be a better choice than two above-mentioned techniques?

Answer (score 3):

1-2: It depends, and it's hard to say that one is inherently preferable. It's also good to consider Jordan form decomposition, which generalizes Eigendecomposition.

- Eigendecomposition, when possible to find, makes computations easier, especially where polynomial and power series are involved.
- Schur decomposition makes more sense when conjugate-transposes (adjoints) are involved
- Schur decomposition is easier to find numerically
- Schur decomposition, unlike Eigendecomposition, works for any square matrix

3: Cholesky decomposition is used for different reasons. It's akin to $LU$ decomposition, but is the better option when possible.